# Trying to replicate SAS Type 3 Tests of Fixed Effects using R

Tags: types, sas

I have a big dataset and trying to replicate SAS results. Almost all my R results match the SAS results except the Type 3 test results. I believe it has to do with using the wrong function to get the desired results. I think I need to use something other than aov() to get the desired results. Attached is a pic of my code and with the results. I think I need to be using a Anova() Type 3 to get the SAS results, but not sure how to do that and would appreciate help.
Thank you!
[R Script with results](https://i.stack.imgur)
[SAS results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIZgS.jpg)

[R Sript with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpzYO.jpg).com/JjNjb.jpg

Comment: it would be helpful to have a reproducible example for your code. You could otherwise see if the method described here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/03/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/

Comment: HI Jonni, thank for the link and I will look into that. Here is my code :                    #Subset Gap Type
Basal<-subset(BoiseGap2020, Type == "B")

#Transformation
Basalloggap<-log(Basal$Gap + 0.001)

#Estimate calculations

#Multivariate model
fit=glm(Basalloggap~(Treatment + Site)^2, data = Basal)


#Univariate estimates 
emmeans(fit,~Site)

emmeans(fit,~Treatment)

#Multivariate estimates 
emmeans(fit,~Site*Treatment)


#P-value calculations
#Type 3 Test of Fixed Effects 
BBG20.av<-aov(fit)
summary(BBG20.av)

Comment: This page really helped https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/anova-in-r/                                                               Install a few packages that I didn't have installed. tidyverse, broom, AICcmodavg, & car. Then using the code below got P-values that matched the SAS results                                                                           
#P-value calculations
#Type 3 Test of Fixed Effects 
BoiseGap2020lm <- lm(Gap ~ Treatment + Site + Treatment*Site, data = Basal)
Anova(BoiseGap2020lm, type = "III")

Comment: Great! You should add your code that worked as an answer below and accept it to help anyone else with a similar issue

Comment: I am having issues with the code being consistent. Not sure why. Load                                                                                 
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(AICcmodavg)
library(car) Code - Basaltype3 <- tibble(BasalBoise, Basallog = Basallog)
newlm <- lm(Basallog ~ Treatment*Site, contrasts = list(Treatment = contr.sum, Site = contr.sum),data = Basaltype3)
Anova(newlm, type = "III") But if I run it on other files it is not accurate and defaults to a number that I am not sure where it is getting it from.

Comment: please add a reproducible example, can't tell why it won't work without being able to replicate it:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example